# IDLE hangs when importing sleekxmpp in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, module, python-idle

Actually IDLE doesnt hang but kind of behaves erratically when the Sleekxmpp library is imported. I can type in the idle but it will not recognize commands. But runs fine on python 3.2 in the same machine. All other packages works fine on the 2.7 version of python. After importing, the idle will not execute any more command entered. It imports fine on Python 2.7.3 command-line interface. Just doesn't work on IDLE. Please help me. I have tried both 'master' and 'develop' version of the package. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. IDLE really is the worst IDE in python, 27. I would use ipython if you really want to use 27, or IDLE in python 3.2.3, if you want to update. ipython can be found [here](http://ipython.org/download.html) and python 3.2.3 can be found [here](http://python.org/download/releases/3.2.3/).